# Hide Login button when session is started

Tags: javascript, if-statement, authentication

I need do hide the login and signup buttons once the user is authenticated. My login is working well, but when I create the *if* statement, it does work as supposed. It is always showing both the login and signup buttons, even when the login is done, which leads me to believe that I'm not writing the condition well (which I've assigned as user). Does it have to do with wrong variable name or am I missing something? Any help is welcome.

layout.hbs:

```
{{#if user}}

  <form action="/logout" method="POST" id="form">
    <button type="submit">Log Out</button>
  </form>

{{else}}
  <a href="/login">Log In</a>

  <a href="/signup">sign up</a>
{{/if}}
```

auth-routes.js:

```
router.get("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  res.render("auth/login");
});

router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('loggin in!');

  const theUsername = req.body.username;
  const thePassword = req.body.password;
  console.log(req.body)
  if (theUsername === "" || thePassword === "") {
    res.render("auth/login", {
      errorMessage: "Please enter both, username and password to sign up."
    });
    return;
  }
  User.findOne({ "username": theUsername })
  .then(user => {
      if (!user) {
        res.render("auth/login", {
          errorMessage: "The username doesn't exist."
        });
        return;
      }
      if (bcrypt.compareSync(thePassword, user.password)) {
        // Save the login in the session!
        req.session.currentUser = user;
        res.redirect("/list");
        console.log('Done!');
      } else {
        console.log('undone!');
        res.render("auth/login", {
          errorMessage: "Incorrect password"
        });
      }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    next(error);
  })
});
```

Comment: Can you make a [Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? You can use https://codesandbox.io to create it, so everyone here can run your website immediately.

Comment: you are accessing the user object but not passing it anywhere. you will have to create a middleware which checks if the person is logged in then passes the user object.

Comment: You're going to need something like `res.render("/list", { user: req.session.currentUser })` for that to work, are you doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to add the user variable inside a render, which I had forgotten.

Comment: In that case, just remove the answer and question.

Comment: A better approach is to create an auth middleware for private routes which automatically passes the user object from session to app.locals